# C# ASP Response.Redirect URL Parameter being moved in output URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, redirect, parameters

I'm using Response.Redirect to to refresh a page with a parameter appended to the end of the URL but for some reason the parameter is being moved to a different part of the URL.

Here's an example, my URL is http://domain.com/en/members/careers/vacancies/?output=html

I want this URL to refresh with the following:
http://domain.com/en/members/careers/vacancies/?output=html&param=1

I want to include the extra parameter so I used the following function:

```
string url = CurrentPage.LinkURL;
Response.Redirect(url+"?output=html&param=1");
```

Yet when the page refreshes it has redirected to the following URL:
http://domain.com/en/?output=html/members/careers/vacancies/

I have no idea why the the output parameter is being put there after /en/ or where my second parameter has gone.

I've been at this for a few hours and I'm going crazy looking at it, any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `CurrentPage.LinkURL`?

Comment: Outputted the value and I got /Templates/Members/Pages/JobListingPage.aspx?id=95415&epslanguage=en this might have something to do with URL rewriting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this instead of CurrentPage.LinkURL. Also in you Response.Redirect take out the "?output=html" as it will already be in your string

```
string URL = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
Response.Redirect(URL + "&param=1");
```

Comment: This does work better thanks, however as this includes the original parameter it means that if I use the function more than once I end up with duplicated parameters e.g &param=1&param=1 but this alright I can make a workaround for this. Thanks!